# How can I declare dynamic String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using String Array declare as `zoom z[]=new String[422];`. But this array stores value from `0` to `32`, so I got `null pointer exception` after looping value `32`.

How to solve this problem in java?

How can I declare a dynamic array in java ?

Comment: If only there was a way of describing some code, like.... I dunno, showing us the code...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You want to use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation (e.g. [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), etc, or [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), etc..), since Java does not have dynamically sized arrays.

```
List<String> zoom = new ArrayList<>();
zoom.add("String 1");
zoom.add("String 2");

for (String z : zoom) {
    System.err.println(z);
}
```

*Edit:*
Here is a more succinct way to initialize your List with an arbitrary number of values using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs):

```
List<String> zoom = Arrays.asList("String 1", "String 2", "String n");
```

Comment: Note, this should be "ArrayList", not "List"; which caused me a few problems.

Comment: Using `List<String>` is correct. For discussion of why, Joshua Bloch addresses use of interfaces in [Effective Java - Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-52-refer-to-objects-by-their.html).

Comment: It causes a compilation error when I try to use it, JDK 1.6 and 1.7. Does not take argument warning, I do believe.

Comment: @EM-Creations The diamond operator was not introduced until 1.7. For 1.6, specify the type for the ArrayList constructor as well (`new ArrayList<String>()`). Used as the body of a method in a valid class, the snippet will compile in 1.7 as is.

Comment: I've tested it on JDK 1.6 and 1.7; did not work. Declaring an ArrayList however solves the problem.

Comment: @EM-Creations Are you importing java.util.List or java.awt.List? The former option worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

no, there is no way to make array length dynamic in java.  you can use `ArrayList` or other `List` implementations instead.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for `Vector`. It's capacity is automatically expanded if needed.  It's not the best choice but will do in simple situations. It's worth your time to read up on `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) method is to be used to create an array with dynamically length.

Multi-dimensional arrays can be created similarly with the [`Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int... dimensions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is the DefaultListModel - Dynamic String List Variable.

**Here is a whole class that uses the DefaultListModel as though it were the TStringList of Delphi.**  The difference is that you can add Strings to the list without limitation and you have the same ability at getting a single entry by specifying the entry int.

FileName: StringList.java

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE_GOES_HERE;

//This is the StringList Class by i2programmer
//You may delete these comments
//This code is offered freely at no requirements
//You may alter the code as you wish
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class StringList {

    public static String OutputAsString(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return GetEntry(list, entry);
    }

    public static Object OutputAsObject(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return GetEntry(list, entry);
    }

    public static int OutputAsInteger(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return Integer.parseInt(list.getElementAt(entry).toString());
    }

    public static double OutputAsDouble(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return Double.parseDouble(list.getElementAt(entry).toString());
    }

    public static byte OutputAsByte(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return Byte.parseByte(list.getElementAt(entry).toString());
    }

    public static char OutputAsCharacter(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        return list.getElementAt(entry).toString().charAt(0);
    }

    public static String GetEntry(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        String result = "";
        result = list.getElementAt(entry).toString();
        return result;
    }

    public static void AddEntry(DefaultListModel list, String entry) {
        list.addElement(entry);
    }

    public static void RemoveEntry(DefaultListModel list, int entry) {
        list.removeElementAt(entry);
    }

    public static DefaultListModel StrToList(String input, String delimiter) {
        DefaultListModel dlmtemp = new DefaultListModel();
        input = input.trim();
        delimiter = delimiter.trim();
        while (input.toLowerCase().contains(delimiter.toLowerCase())) {
            int index = input.toLowerCase().indexOf(delimiter.toLowerCase());
            dlmtemp.addElement(input.substring(0, index).trim());
            input = input.substring(index + delimiter.length(), input.length()).trim();
        }
        return dlmtemp;
    }

    public static String ListToStr(DefaultListModel list, String delimiter) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result = list.getElementAt(i).toString() + delimiter;
        }
        result = result.trim();
        return result;
    }

    public static String LoadFile(String inputfile) throws IOException {
        int len;
        char[] chr = new char[4096];
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        final FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File(inputfile));
        try {
            while ((len = reader.read(chr)) > 0) {
                buffer.append(chr, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public static void SaveFile(String outputfile, String outputstring) {
        try {
            FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter(new File(outputfile));
            f0.write(outputstring);
            f0.flush();
            f0.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**OutputAs** methods are for outputting an entry as int, double, etc... so that you don't have to convert from string on the other side.

**SaveFile & LoadFile** are to save and load strings to and from files.

**StrToList & ListToStr** are to place delimiters between each entry.

ex. 1<>2<>3<>4<> if "<>" is the delimiter and 1 2 3 & 4 are the entries.

**AddEntry & GetEntry** are to add and get strings to and from the DefaultListModel.

**RemoveEntry** is to delete a string from the DefaultListModel.

You use the DefaultListModel instead of an array here like this:

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
//now that you have a list, you can run it through the above class methods.
```