# Java - Create new array without zeros

Tags: arrays, for-loop, zero

I have this array:
`String[][] hej = {{"9.8", "0", "hi", "0"}, {"0", "3.4", "yes", "no"}};`

And I want to create a new array without all the zeros.

I started to create a new array:

`String[][] zero = new String[hej.length][hej[0].length];`

I have tried to only insert the elements which are not zeros with this for loop:

```
for(int c = 0; c < zero.length; c++) {
    int i = 0;
    if(hej[i][c] != "0") {
    zero[i][c] = hej[i][c];
```

But it doesn't work and I cannot understand why.

If I do it without a for loop it's like this:
`   if(hej[0][0] != "0")
        zero[0][0] = hej[0][0];

```
if(hej[0][1] != "0")
    zero[0][1] = hej[0][1];

if(hej[0][2] != "0")
    zero[0][2] = hej[0][2];

if(hej[0][3] != "0")
    zero[0][3] = hej[0][3];`
```

But then I still don't know how to make the array shorter without the spot for the removed zero.

- Anyone who can help me understand why my for loop doesn't work and how I can make a for loop to go through the whole [][] array?
- Anyone who can help me understand how to at the same time create a new dynamic array without the spots from the zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your title supposed to say "array"? And can you just filter the inner lists? If you do it with a for-loop, you'll need 2 nested loops. The second loop checks the inner lists.

Comment: Yes sure. Sorry. Can I edit it?

Comment: You can quite easily. Press "edit" under your post.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone who can help me understand why my for loop doesn't work and how
>   I can make a for loop to go through the whole [][] array?

You have to iterate the two dimensional array with two loops like a `for inside a for loop` as follows

```
   public static void eliminateZerosWithStaticArray() throws Exception {
    String[][] hej = {{"9.8", "0", "hi", "0"}, {"0", "3.4", "yes", "no"}};
            int width = hej.length;
            int height = hej[0].length;
            String[][] zero = new String[width][height];

            for(int c=0; c < width; c++) {
                for(int d=0,i=0; d<height; d++) {
                    if(!"0".equals(hej[c][d])) {
                        zero[c][i] = hej[c][d];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Printing the values within zero array ::: ");
            for(int i=0; i<zero.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<zero[i].length; j++ ) {
                    System.out.println("The values are : "+ zero[i][j]);
                }
            }
    }
```

> Anyone who can help me understand how to at the same time create a new
>   dynamic array without the spots from the zeros?

That is where `ArrayList` comes into existence. Here is an answer on how to [add elements to add elements dynamically into an array in java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601490/how-can-i-declare-dynamic-string-array-in-java)

```
public static void eliminateZerosWithDynamicArray() throws Exception {
        String[][] hej = {{"9.8", "0", "hi", "0"}, {"0", "3.4", "yes", "no"}};
        int width = hej.length;
        int height = hej[0].length;
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>(width);

        //Iterate the original array
        for(int c=0; c < width; c++) {
            List<String> templist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int d=0; d<height; d++) {
                if(!"0".equals(hej[c][d])) {
                    templist.add(hej[c][d]);
                }
                result.add(templist);
            }
        }
        //Print the list content
        for(int c=0; c<result.size(); c++) {
            System.out.println("List content : "+result.get(c));
        }
    }
```